# How to sort nodes of undirected cycle graph using the weights between the nodes?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, geometry

let's look at the **undirected cycle graph** with 7 nodes. From node A you can reach E by using A->G->F->E (or A->B->C->D->E which would be bad because it's 1 step more). Each step counts the same.

The smaller lines are NOT edges, they are the amount of how often you travel from A to E - 3 times. You travel from A to C zero times and so on.

The problem is: I have a much BIGGER undirected circle graph and i want to sort the nodes in a way so that if if every process (see count) gets done, it should be the minimum of processed steps. I can see that A and E should be neighbors to each other because A visits E / E visits A more often. But I can't check every combination with like 30 nodes because it would be literally 29! possibilities.

Any hint for algorithms I can use for this? I googled for hours but searching for this stuff is annoying because I always end up looking at "topologic sort" which has nothing to do with this. I want to swap the nodes - the weights between A and E always stay the same.

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Do you know the "Traveling Salesman Problem"? That's a well-reserved problem which seems to be similar to yours. That said, I don't know how it matters how often you travel to some point, that seems to be a variation that is different from that problem. As a new user here, please make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact problem is called *Equidistant Bi-directional Loop Layout Problem* and [Diptesh Ghosh wrote a journal about it](http://vslir.iima.ac.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/11718/17056/1/WP2015-10-05.pdf). Also, this problems seems to be NP-hard according to other jounals.

There are many similar problems to this and all these problems belong to problem class *facility layout problem*.

Comment: This is interesting stuff. I'm glad that you were able to get an answer, even if it wasn't the answer you were looking for.

Thanks for posting!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the optimal solution? Or just a good-enough solution?

I'm not aware of any way to solve this problem exactly without trying every possible configuration.

If you only need a heuristic solution, I would suggest randomly assigning the nodes to locations, and then checking to see if swapping two adjacent nodes reduces the overall distance. If it does, then you swap the nodes. If it doesn't, then you don't swap the nodes. Continue checking for swappable pairs until you reach a configuration where swapping any two nodes does not improve the overall distance.

This technique may yield the optimal solution, or maybe not. I don't understand the mathematics of the problem well enough to know.

Alternatively, it may be possible to solve the problem through a greedy algorithm. Start with a graph with three of your nodes. Insert the other nodes one-at-a-time. Place each new node in the position that increases the distance total the least. Continue until all the nodes are placed.

Again, this may yield the optimal solution or not.

If you need ONLY the optimal solution and a good-enough solution is useless to you, you could generate several thousand of these problems in the range of 7 to 10 nodes with randomly chosen counts between them. For each graph, find the optimal solution through brute-force, and compute a heuristic solution. If the heuristic algorithm gives the optimal result every single time, then it may be safe to generalize it to the case with 30 nodes.

Edit: If you find a solution to this I'd be curious to know.

Comment: I posted it below.